# PHP Shouldnot Repeat and should be from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to build a script that does two thing.
1) The Numbers should not repeat.
2) The numbers should be from an array called $id.

```
<?php
$a = array(); // final array which will have our id's to display
$id = array(1, 3, 5, 7, 9); //final array should contain a number only from this list
$itemstoshow = 3; // how many items to display
for($i = 0; $i < $itemstoshow; $i++) {
    do {
        $a[$i] = assignid(9);
        $chkid = checkeer($a[$i], $i);
        $chkdata = chkdata($a[$i], $i);
    } while($chkdata == "nonexist" or $chkid == "repeatedid");
}

// display numbers in the array
for($i = 0; $i < $itemstoshow; $i++) {
    echo "Item " . $a[$i] . "--------";
}

// check for redundancy function
function checkeer($x, $y)
{  //first parameter is query aray second is counter
    global $a;
    $err = 0;
    // check if repeating number
    for($i = 0; $i <= $y - 1; $i++) {
        if($x == $a[$i]) {
            $err = 1;
        }
    }
    if($err == 1) {
        return "repeatedid";
    }
}

//check if array $a holds value from $id or not
function chkdata($x, $y)
{
    global $a;
    global $id;
    for($i = 0; $i <= $y - 1; $i++) {
        if($x !== $id[$i]) {
            return "nonexist";
        }
    }

}

//assign id function
function assignid($x)
{
    return rand(1, $x);  
}
```

problem number 1 solved problem number 2 still not solved please help me.
the code should show 3 numbers from 1 to 9 which donot repeat and are in the array $id

Comment: You might want to look into the [in_array function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Comment: I want it to be done in procedural manner. If I don't use the chkdata function, it works fine but it only ensures numbers don't repeat. but somewhere there is a mistake with chkdata function. somebody has to tell me where .

Comment: A hint (which would be what we would do to find the problem) is to [Rubber Duck Debug](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) your code

Comment: no wonder you are a great mind an I'm a beginner . First One :) Thanks for the help

Comment: This might put you in the right track: When you call `$chkid = checkeer($a[$i], $i); $chkdata = chkdata($a[$i], $i);` the second arguments in both functions are the ones you use in the `for`s, so you probably want to make sure you pass usefull values. For example, when you pass `$i` to `chkdata`, (let's say $i = 2), you loop from 0 to 1, checking only if $x is different from 2 of the values in the list. You could use a foreach here. OC, that's just an exampe I spotted.

Comment: Great . I replaced $I for both the functions with the help of foreach. Code runs faster. But the non existing data's from $a gets printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combination of [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) and [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to get random values from the array that has the values your basing the randomization. Take a look:

```
$id = array(1,3,5,7,9); //final array should contain a number only from this list
$itemstoshow = 3;
$values = array_map(function($item) use($id){
    return $id[$item];
}, array_rand($id, $itemstoshow));

print_r($values);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 9
)
```

Running again:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 9
)
```

Comment: thanks very much. If you don't mind please inspect my code and tell me how can I do it in the procedural way. Where am I wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) that selects random keys:

```
$id = array(1,3,5,7,9);
$result = array_intersect_key($id, array_flip(array_rand($id, 3)));
```

Or you can [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array and take for example the 3 first items:

```
$id = array(1,3,5,7,9);
$temp = $id;
shuffle($temp);
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $result[] = $temp[$i];
}
```

Comment: thanks. I will actually inplement
$id = array(1,3,5,7,9); //final array should contain a number only from this list
$itemstoshow = 3;
$values = array_map(function($item) use($id){
    return $id[$item];
}, array_rand($id, $itemstoshow));
I am a newbie. Sorry for irritating you :)

print_r($values);